# How to refer to bootstrap.css in jsp file under WEB-INF

Tags: css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications, file-access

How do I access the bootstrap.css file which resides under WEB-INF/css as below ?
 [image: File Structure]

When I load the page it is giving me a resource not found error message.

I tried the following in the jsp file

```
<link type="text/css" href= "css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Just to note this is **not a spring project**.

Comment: is it a path problem? have you tried `../css/bootstrap.css` ? or does it have to use an absolute path? or is it a localhost problem?

Comment: Yes I have tried ../css/bootstrap.css. It does not have an absolute path.Yes it is a localhost problem.

Comment: Why are you putting stuff under web-inf?

Comment: What WEB-INF is good for is making resources unavailable to the user.  That's why you put your class files in there...so the user can't download your classfiles and steal your code. But CSS you want accessible...